# Using Sentiwordnet with TextBlob

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, textblob, senti-wordnet

Is there a way I can conduct sentiment analysis with TextBlob, as NLP, using Sentiwordnet, as it's corpora database?

Currently, I believe TextBlob is using other corpora databases to do sentiment analysis from the download_corpora.py, but I do not know which ones are actually being used for the analysis.

(I know I can use NLTK, but I find TextBlob more powerful, as it calls NLTK.)

Comment: I looked at your question, I went to TextBlob and read the first page and then came back to your question and I am struggling here to understand exactly what you are asking.  Can you clarify this and make it conform to a question per the help pages?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what OP is asking is, is there a SentiWordNet model NLTK that can be used in TextBlob.

Out of the box, the answer is no.

From TextBlob's wiki: The textblob.sentiments module contains two sentiment analysis implementations, PatternAnalyzer (based on the pattern library) and NaiveBayesAnalyzer (an NLTK classifier trained on a movie reviews corpus). https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#sentiment-analyzers